# Mobx with useEffect() not rendered data in component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-react-lite

I'm new to React and Mobx.

I want to init component by data from GET-request in useEffect().
There are simple component with mobx store:

```
import { autorun } from "mobx";
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useStore } from "./store";

const TestPage: React.FC = () => {

    const { testStore } = useStore();
    const isCancelled = useRef(false);

    useEffect(
        () => autorun(
            () => {
            
            const fetchData = async () => {
                const data = await fetch('/api/dictionaries/sources?subject=MATH');
                const json = await data.json();

                if (!isCancelled.current) {
                    testStore.setList(json);
                }
            }

            fetchData().catch(console.error);
            return () => {
                isCancelled.current = true;
            };

        }
        )
        , [testStore, testStore.setList]
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is test list</h1>
            {testStore.list.map((i) => <div key={i.id}>{i.id}: {i.name}</div>)}
        </div>
    );
}

export default TestPage;
```

test-store.ts:

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";

export interface Item {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

export default class TestStore {

    list: Item[];
 
    constructor() {
        this.list = [];
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    setList = (list: any) => {
        this.list = list; 
        console.log("In setList: " + this.list);
    }

}
```

store.tx:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import TestStore from "./test-store";

const store = {
    testStore: new TestStore(),
};

export const StoreContext = createContext(store);

export const useStore = () => {
  return useContext<typeof store>(StoreContext);
};

export default store;
```

Response from server is received, but list in component is not rendered:
[image]

However, if recompile to a hot one, the data in the component is rendered. So I think the problem is asynchronous execution. Can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using HOC ```observer``` from ```mobx-react``` or ```mobx-react-lite```  ?https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html#using-external-state-in-observer-components

Comment: Thanks, I added the observer and it worked. My main application didn't have makeAutoObservable, only "action" and "observable" and it didn't work. I'll try to put makeAutoObservable everywhere instead of decorators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For making the React Components reactive to the state changes in mobX, we need to wrap the components an observer(), which is a HoC. You can use either **mobx-react** or **mobx-react-lite** both works fine.

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"
const Component = observer(() => {
   return (
      // JSX Codes that uses mobX states
   )
})

export default Component
```

Otherwise, you can also do it like this

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"
    const Component = () => {
       return (
          // JSX Codes that uses mobX states
       )
    }
    
    export default observer(Component)
```

Only then, you can trigger rerender. Othewise, if you have to use the context API, then I think you have to use **useState()** to trigger the UI render.

Comment: Thank you, with observer() it worked!  My main application didn't have makeAutoObservable, only "action" and "observable" and it didn't work. Can you explain to me what is the difference between decorators and makeAutoObservable?

Comment: Decorators in general are wrappers. So when you add a @decorator at the beginning of a class, then the class inherits the properties of the wrapper ( decorator )

Previously in class-based react components, decorators were used to make the components reactive to mobX states. But, then the mobX team developed packages like mobx-react and mobx-react-lite, which has this observer() that we wrap around the functional react components, which I guess works the same as decorators under the hood.

makeAutoObservable() is for defining observables, actions, and computed properties in the mobx class.

Comment: I hope this clarifies some bits in your head.